# Not able to redirect to a url in perl

Tags: perl

I am using an Admintool. I have a Login as Partner button in admin tool. When i click on the admin tool i want to go to a users profile directly without login. I am using a html page where there is a header and under that header i want that users profile.

So what i am doing is i am getting the url for users profile and redirecting to that url.

I am getting the header page but under it am getting the login page to go to the users profile. When i am directly opening the url i am able to go the users profile direclty .

But when i am redirecting  i am getting the login page to go to the users profile. i am using below code to redirect to a url.

```
## Redirecting the partner to abc.com
                my $r = new CGI;
                print STDERR " url is $result\n";
                print $r->redirect( -URL => $result);
                close(STDOUT);
                exit(0);
```

Please help

Comment: `$content=get $result;print $content;`

Comment: @drt Why should both server and client request the same content if it can be done with a redirect?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say whether you wanted to view the user's profile as the public would, as user might (to edit their own profile) or as admin user.

If you need to view the page as if you are logged in as a user, here's how I have solved a case like that:

In our session, we have a "real_user_id" and "effective_use_id". Usually they are the same, and in most places in the session handling, we check the "effective_user_id". However, in an admin area, sometimes we want to login in as another user so we can see things as they do. In that case, we have a function in the admin area to set the "effective user id" of the admin user to another user. This allows us to effectively "log in" as the user as without a password, but because the system can still see the "real user id", we can also build an option to return back to the being a normal admin user.

You might be having a problem because while you are redirecting to the right page, the page is redirecting back to the login screen because you aren't logged in that user. You can review what's happening on the command line by issuing a request by hand like this:

```
HEAD -sSe 'http://example.com/users-profile-page-to-redirect-to'
```

(The 'HEAD' tool comes from the LWP::UserAgent perl module).

You may need to update the authentication of your "user profile page" so that both normal users and admin users are allowed to see it. How you do that depends on how you've implemented authorization in your system.

Comment: i want to view the users profile as the public would.. from cgi file i am going to html file where frames are used.. dont know the correct problem. so what i did is without going to html page i have redirected directly to users profile and i am able to view the users profile as the public would. I will also check the command which you have advised, may be i can get to know what went wrong when i am redirecting from html page.. Thanks for your reply.